# Call function with arra out of bounds access

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, struct, exploit

so I've got a buggy C file in which i need to find an exploit. I have found a bug when accessing the following struct:

```
#define BOARD_SIZE 10

typedef int (*turn_function_t)(struct board *);
typedef void (*win_function_t)(struct board *);

struct board {
    uint8_t f1[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    uint8_t f2[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    win_function_t win;
    turn_function_t turn;
    int avail;
};

int do_shot(struct board *board, int strength, int x, int y) {
    if(!(x >= 0 && x <= BOARD_SIZE && y >= 0 && y <= BOARD_SIZE)) {
        return SHOT_ERR_EINVAL;
    }

    /* If there was already a sunken ship, return error */
    if(board->f1[x][y] && !board->f2[x][y])
        return SHOT_ERR_SUNKEN;

    /* Now perform shot */
    if(!board->f2[x][y])
        return SHOT_WATER;

    board->f2[x][y] -= strength;

    if(!board->f2[x][y])
        return SHOT_SUNKEN;
    return SHOT_HIT;
}
```

The bug I found is a wrong index check when accessing array `f2`. I can chose the index as input (index can be anything from 0 to 10 inclusive). I need to find a way to call the function `win` (doesn't matter which parameter). My question now is is there any way I can use that out of bounds access to call the function `win` since the function pointer is stored directly after the array f2 inside the struct?

Comment: Show the code you are describing as a [mre] please.

Comment: Please clarify whether this is a) asking for help with a homework situation b) asking about how to act morally sound in case you found a potentially security relevant bug in code by a different author c) asking for help with exploiting a bug you found, for your own benefit, against the interests of the author of the code d) some other situation which I did not think of

Comment: i guess it falls under category d). This is an assignment of my university in order to be accepted to some practical course on hacking. However I have not done any course on it-security fundamentals and therefore cannot do that practical course. I'm tring to solve the assignment only out of curiosity and because I want to start learning some it security basics

Comment: That seems a) to me. Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

of cause it can be done easily. 
I show you an example code below. 
I use pragma pack(1) for byte align and use print to find the address of the function, and finally I got it. 
the code may can not be run on your computer. 
but your can find the address by print to make bounds address equal to function address. 
it may be f[0][-1] on your computer

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*turn_function_t)(struct board *);

#pragma pack(1)
struct board
{
    turn_function_t win;
    int f[10][10];
};
#pragma pack(0)

int win(struct board *b)
{
    printf("Win!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct board b;
    b.win = win;
    // printf("%p\n", &b.f[0][-2]);
    // printf("%p\n", &b.win);
    (*(turn_function_t *)(&b.f[0][-2]))(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I misorder the f1,f2 and function,then you should find your function address use f2[9][10].may be not exactly but around there